# How can I compress a Directory then return the resulting byte array, without physically creating zip file on disk?

Tags: c#, .net

Note that I'm writing my code in .net MVC project.

I have a directory(folder) which contains sub-directories and files. My task is to write a function that returns a FileResult of the compressed directory.
Right now my approach is like:

```
     ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(originalFolder, zipFilePath); // this line create a zip file physically
     return File(zipFilePath,"application/zip",zipFileName);
```

Everything works fine but I'm wondering if I could have a more faster way to return the FileResult directly by the byte[] from the memorystream.

The above approach requires me to delete the zip file manually after the function call. Also I assume that the byte[] of the zip file has already been created inside the function: ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory. Writing the result physically onto the disk is just unnecessary.

I'm struggling with a new approach,from https://www.carlrippon.com/zipping-up-files-from-a-memorystream/  :

```
    byte[] fileBytes = null;

 using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        // create a zip
        using (System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive zip = new System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive(memoryStream, 
        System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            // interate through the source files
            foreach (SourceFile f in sourceFiles)
            {
                // add the item name to the zip
                System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveEntry zipItem = zip.CreateEntry(f.Name + "." + f.Extension);
                // add the item bytes to the zip entry by opening the original file and copying the bytes
                using (System.IO.MemoryStream originalFileMemoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(f.FileBytes))
                {
                    using (System.IO.Stream entryStream = zipItem.Open())
                    {
                        originalFileMemoryStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        fileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
    return File(fileBytes, "application/zip");
```

But the above code does not deal with the sub directory issue. Anyone has idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DotNetZip Library](https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd) to do it,and below is asp.net mvc demo and link I write for you.

Controller :

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Ionic.Zip;
using System.IO;

namespace ZipDemo
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public FileResult Download()
        {
            var bytes = default(byte[]);
            using (var zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                zip.AddEntry("text.txt", new byte[] {});
                zip.AddEntry("text\\text.txt", new byte[] {});

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    zip.Save(ms);
                    bytes = ms.ToArray();
                } 
            }       
            return File(bytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip);
        }
    }
}
```

View :

```html
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- CSS Includes -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1>Download ZIP</h1>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Download","Home"))
                {

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit" />
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Online Demo Link ZipDoNet_MemoryStream | C# Online Compiler | .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OahvFS)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! So that the AddEntry function does the magic. All I need to do is just iterate through the sub-directories names.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are dealing with similar problems:

```
            var bytes = default(byte[]);
            using (var zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(originalFolder);
                //Here you may need to do recursion for multi-level sub-directories
                foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in dir.GetDirectories())
                {
                    var subName = diSourceSubDir.Name;
                    foreach (FileInfo fi in diSourceSubDir.GetFiles())
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = null;
                        using (FileStream fs = fi.OpenRead())
                        {
                            buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
                            fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
                            zip.AddEntry(subName + "\\" + fi.Name, buffer);
                        }
                    }
                }

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    zip.Save(ms);
                    bytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
            return File(bytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip);
```